# Create a new section in a standard page

Tags: standardlayout

I'm not sure if this possible or not but I'm looking for a way to add a section under standard page as shown below in the screen shot as an example:

The purpose of doing so that I should be able to add custom URL links. Is that possible or do I have to create a Visualforce page?

[image]

Comment: no this is not possible.. instead you can create a vf page with apex enhancedlist and add a new section below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page is not customizable.

You have to go for a new visualforce page and new custom tab.

Replicate the functionality on standard page onto your custom vf page, if need be.

Sample Code: This makes most of the page.

**Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Contract" extensions="ContractTabExtension">
    <apex:enhancedList type="Contract" height="300" rowsPerPage="10" id="ContractList"/>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Recently Viewed Contracts">
        <apex:pageblockTable var="ct" value="{!RecentlyViewedContractList}">
            <apex:column value="{!ct.Name}" />
        </apex:pageblockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

**Extension Class: ContractTabExtension**

```
public with sharing class ContractTabExtension {
    public list<RecentlyViewed> RecentlyViewedContractList {get; set;}
    public ContractTabExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        RecentlyViewedContractList = new list<RecentlyViewed>();
        RecentlyViewedContractList = [SELECT Id, Name
                                      FROM RecentlyViewed 
                                      WHERE Type IN ('Contract')
                                      ORDER BY LastViewedDate DESC];
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have or redirect me to the VF page that resembles the same as standard page?

Comment: i added some sample code in my answer

Comment: I did't know that there is type called `RecentlyViewed` 1+